# Removing event-handlers in destructors in case both publisher and subscriber hold reference to each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, memory-leaks, event-handling

Lets say we have the following model:

```
    public class Bar<T>:List<T>
    {
        public delegate void CollectionChangedDelegate();
        public event CollectionChangedDelegate CollectionChanged;
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        Bar<object> MyCollection = new Bar<object>();

        public Foo()
        {
            MyCollection.CollectionChanged += new Bar<object>.CollectionChangedDelegate(MyCollection_CollectionChanged);
        }

        public void MyCollection_CollectionChanged()
        {
            //Do Something
        }

        ~Foo() //Would this work ?
        {
            MyCollection.CollectionChanged -= MyCollection_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }
```

Could the destructor of Class `Foo` be called in this case ?

Comment: You should not use Destructors, use the IDisposable interface instead. Answer to your question: If no other living object holds an reference to the Foo class, they will be both collected, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775520/c-sharp-garbage-collector-cross-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pointless to do so. Let's assume that there is such a subscription. Now, for us to get to the `~Foo` method we must be being collected, so we must be unreachable. Because of how events work, subscriptions *make us reachable* (the publisher has a reference to the subscriber) - so we can deduce that `MyCollection` is *also* unreachable. If it wasn't, we wouldn't be being collected.

And if `MyCollection` is unreachable, then either it has already been collected, or it is *about to be* collected. There is no need to unsubscribe.

Remove `~Foo`: it is pointless here; actually, it is *worse* than pointless - in addition to serving no useful purpose, it forces the garbage collector to push this object through an extra step (the finalizer queue).

You might, however, want to add some kind of *deterministic* clean-up that does this; as Joroen notes, `IDisposable` may be of use - however, it is hard to say whether it is appropriate in the case without knowing more context.

Comment: Okay, to make it simple .. Foo will be collected no matter what right ? And there is no need for the destructor ?
And you said MyCollection has to be unreachable, how can i guarantuee that ? Lets say i made and instance of Foo, thus and instance of Bar (MyCollection) would be made too, how can i guarantuee that MyCollection will be collected and made unreachable by the end of the scope ?

Comment: Also just for the Note class Foo represents a Business entity in the system i am working on, and is thoroughly used every where (Thats why IDisposable is not an option). I am trying to figure out if it could be the cause of a memory leak ? One of the developers in our team, claims it is and that he added the destructor and tested its effect on cleaning the memory. I would like to make sure of that

Comment: @SirajMansour I was talking about the scenario where `~Foo` is being called: for that to happen, we can *deduce* that the collection was unreachable (otherwise we wouldn't have got there). As for keeping it unreachable - well, at the moment it is a private field - the only thing that can know about it is the `Foo` instance. Based on the *code shown* (and ***only*** the code shown), I say again: that `~Foo` is *worse* than useless. It has no good effects, and a definite negative effect.

Comment: One more question ? Could this pattern be a cause of a memory leak in case the destructor wasn't written ? In case it was ? Considering that Foo is a buisiness entity used everywhere in the system.

Comment: @SirajMansour no, not in the code shown; again - in the scenario where this code runs, we **already know** that both the object and collection are unreachable. It serves no purpose ***whatsoever***.

Answer (score 3):

first of all, I believe that you are trying to write ObservableCollection
You can find info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx.

Now, if my object holds data-members that have a need to dispose, I would implement IDisposable and there I would dispose them, or at least remove the event subscription.
implment it like that:

```
class Foo:Idisposable 
{
    public void Dispose(bool b)
    {
         MyCollection.CollectionChanged -= MyCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to write that, actually its already written, and i am working on a memory leak. I'am wondering if this would be a cause of a memory leak, because the class Foo represents a Business entity in the system i am working on, and is thoroughly used every where.