# Mapping protocol/delegates in Swift to c#

Tags: c#, ios, swift

I'm trying to understand the usage of protocol and delegates in Swift and their equivalence in c# for Xamarin.iOS.

Microsoft has a decent documentation about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/delegates-protocols-and-events) but for me it lacks the swift or objectiveC counterpart of c# code to allow me to understand what to do.

I'm in the process of porting an [existing Swift gist](https://gist.github.com/smswz/393b2d6237b7837234015805c600ada2#file-gridlayout-swift) to c# Xamarin iOS.

I have this protocol:

```
protocol GridLayoutDelegate: class {
    func scaleForItem(inCollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView, withLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UInt
    func itemFlexibleDimension(inCollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView, withLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout, fixedDimension: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    func headerFlexibleDimension(inCollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView, withLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout, fixedDimension: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
}
```

That I have converted to:

```
public interface IGridLayoutDelegate
{
    uint ScaleForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath);
    nfloat ItemFlexibleDimension(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, nfloat fixedDimension);
    nfloat HeaderFlexibleDimension(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, nfloat fixedDimension);
}
```

So far so good.

Later in the code I have this (for now) strange declaration:

```
weak var delegate: GridLayoutDelegate?
```

What concerns me is that it is never assigned later in the swift code.

For now I have my c# class declared as:

```
public class GridLayout : UICollectionViewLayout, IGridLayoutDelegate
{
...
}
```

What would be the corresponding code in c#?

Answer (score 0):

`Swift` language uses [Automatic Reference Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting#Swift), so it needs `weak var` to deal with memory leaks, caused by circular references.

As opposing, `C#` uses Garbage Collector, which handles circular references by itself without extra manual effort (more detailed here: [Garbage collector and circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840567/garbage-collector-and-circular-reference) . This works when both objects in the circular reference have similar lifetime, if one of the objects outlives another without unsubscribing there might pop up [Lapsed listener problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapsed_listener_problem))

So I think in `C#` you just need:

```
public class GridLayout : UICollectionViewLayout, IGridLayoutDelegate
{
    private IGridLayoutDelegate @delegate;
```

I'm not familiar with `Xamarin`, so I cannot say for sure how `@delegate` should be initialized.