# Can Dart's garbage collector handle circular references?

Tags: dart, garbage-collection

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840567/garbage-collector-and-circular-reference) question but regarding Dart's garbage collector. If it cannot then how can I make it eligible for garbage collector? Does setting `B.a` to `null` is going to work?