# C# Events Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

When does these unsubscribed events memory leak occurs? Should I write destructor or implement IDisposable to unsubscribe an event?

Comment: Simple rule: Don't use finalizers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let's say that **A** references **B**. Furthermore, say you think you're done with **B** and expect it to be garbage collected.

Now, if **A** is *reachable*[1], **B** won't be garbage collected, despite the fact that "you're done with it". This is, in all essence, a *memory leak*[2]

If **B** subscribes to an event in **A**, then we have the same situation: **A** has a reference to **B** via the event handler delegate.

So, when is this a problem? Only when the referencing object is reachable, as mentioned above. In this case, there **can** be a leak when a **Foo** instance isn't used any longer:

```
class Foo
{
    Bar _bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
        _bar.Changed += BarChanged;
    }

    void BarChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

The reason why there **can** be a leak is that the **Bar** instance passed in the constructor **can** have a longer lifetime than the **Foo** instance using it. The subscribed event handler **can** then keep the **Foo** alive.

In this case you need to provide a way to unsubscribe from the event to not get a memory leak. One way of doing that is by letting **Foo** implement **IDisposable**. The upside of that is that it clearly signals to the class consumer that he need to call **Dispose()** when done. Another way is to have separate **Subscribe()** and **Unsubscribe()** methods, but that doesn't convey the type's expectations - they are too optional to call and introduce a temporal coupling.

My recommendation is:

```
class sealed Foo : IDisposable
{
    readonly Bar _bar;
    bool _disposed;

    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            _disposed = true;
            _bar.Changed -= BarChanged;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
class sealed Foo : IDisposable
{
    Bar _bar;

    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_bar != null)
        {
            _bar.Changed -= BarChanged;
            _bar = null;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

On the other hand, when the referencing object **isn't** reachable, there **can't** be a leak:

```
class sealed Foo
{
    Bar _bar;

    public Foo()
    {
        _bar = new Bar();
        _bar.Changed += BarChanged;
    }

    void BarChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

In this case any **Foo** instance will always outlive its composed **Bar** instance. When a **Foo** is unreachable, so will its **Bar** be. The subscribed event handler cannot keep the **Foo** alive here. The downside of this is that if **Bar** is a dependency in need of being mocked in unit testing scenarios, it can't (in any clean way) be explicitly instantiated by the consumer, but needs to be injected.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak

Comment: In the case where the referencing object isn't reachable, don't you have a circular reference, which would keep both objects alive? A Foo has a reference to _bar and _bar has a reference to that Foo through it's handler. Am I wrong to think this is a circular reference? Is the C# GC smart enough to handle circular references and garbage collect non the less? Or do we actually still find ourselves with a memory leak?

Comment: The circular references won't affect garbage collection. The reason is perfectly described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/400727/6345

Answer (score 6):

An event handler contains a strong reference to the object that declares the handler (in the delegate's `Target` property).

Until the event handler is removed (or until the object owning the event is no longer referenced anywhere), the object containing the handler will not be collected.

You can fix this by removing the handler when you no longer need it (perhaps in `Dispose()`).
A finalizer cannot help, because the finalizer would only run after it can be collected.

Comment: So shouldn't i remove all event handlers manually just for safety?

Comment: Depends on whether the object which declares the event is collected in time. This is not the case for a static event, so you should unregister your handler in the manner described.

Comment: @fex: You should take out the time to figure out how long each object will last and remove where necessary.  If you want to produce a reliable program, it is very important that you understand how you want it to work.