# How to handle property changed event of a property in One class from another class in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

Say I have description property in one class:

```
public string Description
{
    get
    {
        return _description;
    }

    set
    {
        _description = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
    }
}
```

I would like to monitor the change in these value in some other type. How do I wire up?

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe the event PropertyChanged.

```
myModel.PropertyChanged+=(s,e)=>{ /* your handler here */};
```

as the @stijn comment point, unsubscribing can be required if the model became unused to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: it's worth mentioning unsubscribing might be needed in some cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133551/c-sharp-events-memory-leak